# Subtract two dates in sql to hhhh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to subtract two dates and get hhhh:mm:ss when the number of hours may be greater than 24

And I do not want to limit the number of hours by hhhh.
I have two dates, 
`date1='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'` and 
`date2='1900-01-02 01:00:00.000'`. 
I want to get:

```
date2-date1 = '25:00:00.0'
```

Comment: Which version of SQL (SQLServer, MySQL, Oracle, etc) are you using? This will affect the answers offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make it only in a character data type because range of data type time 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime = '19000101 00:00:00.000',
        @date2 datetime = '19000102 01:00:00.000'

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, @date1, @date2) AS nvarchar(5))+ ':00:00.0'
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1c06/23)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your table columns.. Here i have two columns i-e `time1` and `time2` with the attribute of `DATE`.. Below is the query for subtracting ...

`select to_char(Time1,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MM:SSAM'),to_char(Time2,'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MM:SSAM'),(Time1-Time2)*1440 from Table_Name`;

Comment: thanke you for your anwer. i have two dates,             date1='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' and                      date2='1900-01-02 01:00:00.000'. I want to get                 date2-date1 = '25:00:00.0'

Comment: so you can easily find it your date by subtracting. you are new so you can also mark my answer correct .. Thanks

Comment: if I do: select convert(time,dateadd(ms,sum(DATEDIFF(ms, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '1900-01-02 01:00:00.000')),0)) i get the result 01:00:00.0000000 and not 25:00:00.00

Comment: what you want ..i answered it to you... or explain your question so that i can understand Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also, in T-SQL there is a `DATEDIFF` function:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

For example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2005-12-31 23:59:59', '2006-01-01 00:00:00');
```

In oracle you could see this link helpful - http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_date_time.html

In MySQL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub